# Points of Discontinuity of the function

Tags: continuity

Find points of discontinuity  of

$$f(x)=\lim\frac{\left(1+\sin (π/x)\right)^n-1}{\left(1+\sin (π/x)\right)^n+1}, \,x \in (0,1).$$

My Attempt:

When $x$ is irrational,
$0<x<1 \implies 1<1/x \implies \pi <\pi/x \implies 0< \sin(\pi/x) 
\implies 1<1+\sin(\pi/x),$

so that

$$f(x)=\lim\frac{1- 1/(1+\sin \pi/x)^n}{1+ 1/(1+\sin \pi/x)^n},$$ that is $f(x)=1$ as $$\lim 1/(1+\sin \pi/x)^n=0.$$

Again when $x$ is rational $f(x)=0,$ so $f$ is discontinuous on $(0,1).$

Am I right?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you wrote. For the example, with your "f(x)=lim{(1+sin pi/x)^n-1}/{(1+sin pi/x)^n+1}". You have a "lim", but don't state what the limit you're taking is. It would appear it should be for $n \to \infty$. Also, I don't understand what $x$ being irrational or rational has to do with it, including what you're saying about their results. One thing which would help is to use MathJax to format your math statements, with this [tuturial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helping to explain the basics.

Comment: next time surely i will take help from MathJax

Comment: yes  i wnt to ask the question which is edited

Comment: when x is rational  argument of sin is n.pi so f(X)=0

Comment: if i am in wrong direction plz correct me by solving the problem